# What is the simplest way to apply themeing

Tags: c#, uwp, themes, resourcedictionary

Let's say I have a ResourceDictionary with:

**UPDATE:**

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AquaBrush" Color="#257D8E"/> 

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenBrush" Color="Green"/>
```

Lets say this is my app:
[image]

I have a combobox with items (Aqua, Green and Gray) When i select the Aqua Button, it should display like this:
[image]
 and the Button and other control I want to set should update its background to aqua too.

How can I just bind the SplitView , Button , other control's background to one property and when I select the "aqua" it will use the "AquaBrush" and when i select the "Green", it will use the "GreenBrush"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have SolidColorBrush resource defined in your XAML, you can do this from code behind for changing the background color based on conditions at runtime :

```
if(Some Condition){
    relativePanelName.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["NavPaneBackgroundBrushBlue"];
}else {
    relativePanelName.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["NavPaneBackgroundBrushGreen"];
}
```

Hope this helps..!

---

**Edit :**

Additionally, not only can you define static resources of your own, you can also use system's [theme resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/xaml-theme-resources) .

For example you can access system's accent color like this :

C#

```
var color = (Color)this.Resources["SystemAccentColor"];
```

Xaml

```
<Grid.Background>
   <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource SystemAccentColor}"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

---

**EDIT 2 :** 
Since the Question has been changed and framed in a better way it is pretty clear that you want to know about **Application wide Theme-ing** . 
You can get application wide theme-ing in multiple ways,so here's one :

- Define an application resource in you App.Xaml so that it is
  available through out your application .

  [image]
- Now these resources will be available through out all the pages.You can access them like this :

[image]

This way you will have app-wide theme.

You can also access the application resources from code behind :

```
gridName.Background=new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["ColorThree"]);
```

---

**Edit 3 :**

In you app.xaml :

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="ThemeColor">#f4425f</Color>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="UserAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource ThemeColor}"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

On click of your button simply change the color of the "UserAccentBrush" and it will be reflected in all controls that use the brush..

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var brush = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["UserAccentBrush"];

            if (cb.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                switch (cb.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 242, 101, 34);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 232, 10, 90);
                        break;
                }
            }
}
```

*Please note that I am directly using application.current.resources, you might have to modify the code a bit..*

If you need to save this color and apply it next time user opens the application you will need to save it to application settings (or any settings file you may be maintaining) and on load of the application apply the color change code..!

Comment: There are more generic ways of doing the same, this would be strictly based on colors. I would consider using a resource dictionary and app themes

Comment: okay , but is there a better way or right way for my scenario?

Comment: Since NicoTing has already defined resources in his resource dictionary I have provided a solution for applying the resources at runtime..I have edited my answer to add more information regarding the same..

Comment: Updated the Question

Comment: Updated my answer..which explains how you can define and access application wide resources..

Comment: @Pratyay yes I have added my ThemeResource to my app.xaml
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ThemeResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: So what i want is, when the user selects a theme from combobox , all my controls background should update to that selected color theme even the controls from my page 2

Comment: I have updated my answer..I think defining a resource in app.xaml and overriding it is the easiest way of applying application wide theme-ing!

Comment: @Pratyay Ok , Where or how can I convert color to argb?
 Thank You :)

Comment: There are many online utility websites that provide easy interface to convert hex to rgba and back..like [this](https://www.hexcolortool.com/)..or you can simply google **"hex color"** and you can use google's alternative for this..